# drag and drop the selected text from one Firstname to Lastname in Facebook Sign up form

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

String Name ="firstname";

WebElement eleFirstName = driver.findElement(By.name(Name));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

String EName ="lastname";

WebElement eleLastName = driver.findElement(By.name(EName));

eleLastName.sendKeys("Helllos");

Action action = actions.doubleClick(eleLastName).dragAndDrop(eleLastName, eleFirstName).build();

action.perform();
```

Below is the  code for the drag and drop the selected text from lastname to firstname field in facebook sign up form please check the code suggest the problems which I had done.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can not drag and drop text to/from text field.
You can use getText() and sendKeys() methods to do the same action.

```
String eleFirstName = driver.findElement(By.name(Name)).getText();
WebElement eleLastName = driver.findElement(By.name(EName));
eleLastName.sendKeys(eleFirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to send the same input to both the fields, why not use the same String variable

`String Name ="firstname";`

to `.sendKeys(Name);`

to both the Webelements `eleFirstName` and `eleLastName`. That way you `DragAndDrop` won't come into scene and will guarantee proper results every time.